# Capturing the zoomed in portion of a UIImage as if it was it's own image

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage, quartz-2d

I have the following scenario:
 - An image (taken as a camera picture)
 - image is embedded in an UIImageView
 - image view is embedded in a UIScrollView

I can successfully zoom and pan. What I want to do now is when a user zooms in on a portion of the image, be able to treat that zoom as if it was the sole thing inside a UIImageView. I want them to be able to zoom out again, so I don't want to lose the original image (which tosses out answers which crop the image that I've seen).

What's happening now is that I can do the zoom, but the zoomed image gets shoved up to 0,0 as if I zoomed in on the upper left corner of the image (instead of wherever the user zoomed).

I don't have much in scrollViewDidEndZooming, but that's where I'm assuming the code is going to go. I'm doing something like:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
    CGFloat zoomReciprocal = 1.0f / scale;

    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(imageHolder.image.size.width * ((1.0f - zoomReciprocal) / 2.0f), imageHolder.image.size.height * ((1.0f - zoomReciprocal) / 2.0f));
    CGRect croppedRect = CGRectMake(offset.x, offset.y, imageHolder.image.size.width * zoomReciprocal, imageHolder.image.size.height * zoomReciprocal);

    //and have tried things like:
    //[imageHolder.image drawInRect:croppedRect];
    //scrollView.contentSize = [self maximumUsableFrame].size;
    //scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
}
```

What I want to do is basically be able to zoom in to a portion of the image, and have the rest of the methods think that's the current image. Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the question, and not sure if this is still relevant - but what you mean is if you do something like self.imageView.image you would like to retrieve just the "zoomed" portion?